# Particle System Subsampling

Tags: particles

Any ideas how to subsample with particles, as my animation travels too fast between frames for the particles to keep up? I'm using 2.83.0[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm talking from an older version here.  In the particles 'Physics' tab, with Newtonian physics selected there's a slot called 'Subframes'  That might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found it was actually under object velocity in 2.9!

Comment: Good to know you got there, that's what counts!  :)